# Mi componente card corta el contenido al iniciar sesión en la app

Tags: html, bootstrap, css3, ionic

He creado un `componente Card` para reutilizarlo en la sección Home de mi aplicación.

Dicho card lleva un poco de las etiquetas de `Ionic 6`, un poco de `Bootstrap` y un poco de `CSS Grid`.

Sucede que al momento que el usuario inicia sesión (desde el Formulario), al llevarlo a la ruta Home los cards se muestran recortados. Si se recarga la página esto se soluciona pero no debería de suceder.

Probando un poco he notado que el problema está en el ion-card pero aún no logro dar con una solución.

Así debería verse siempre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así se ve cuando se inicia sesión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```css
/*<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Clases Reutilizables -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->*/
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
/*  */
.cortarTexto{ /* Cortamos la información a 2 líneas cuando el texto es muy largo */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}




/*<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Contenedor Principal -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->*/
.content-grid{
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* grid-auto-rows: 12rem; */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(min(100%, 400px), 1fr));
}




/*<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Estilos del Card -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->*/
ion-card{
  height: 100%;
  background: #36375E;
}





/*<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Estilos del Contenedor IMG -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->*/
.contenedor-img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.contenedor-img img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -ms-border-radius: 10px;
  -o-border-radius: 10px;
}




/*<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Estilos del Contenedor Titulo -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->*/
.contenedor-titulo{
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
}
.contenedor-titulo h2{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #D2EBE2;
}




/*<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Estilos del Contenedor Texto -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->*/
.contenedor-txt{
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
}
.contenedor-txt p{
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #F1F1F1;
}




/*<!-- ============================================================== -->
<!-- Estilos del Contenedor Botón -->
<!-- ============================================================== -->*/
.contenedor-boton{
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}
.contenedor-boton button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #D3DF4E;
  color: #00013A;
  clip-path: polygon(6% 0, 100% 0, 100% 20%, 100% 80%, 94% 100%, 20% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 20%);
}
.contenedor-boton button:hover{
  background: #ecf85f;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-grid  p-3">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div class="row contenedor-row">

      <!-- Imagen -->
      <div class="col-6 col-md-6 contenedor-img p-1 p-md-2">
        <img alt="Silhouette of mountains" *ngIf="!item.portada" [src]="item.portada | noimage" />
        <img alt="Silhouette of mountains" *ngIf="item.portada" [src]="urlApiImg + item.portada" />
      </div>

      <!-- Información del Programa -->
      <div class="col-6 col-md-6 p-1 p-md-2">

        <!-- Titulo -->
        <div class="col-12  contenedor-titulo">
          <ion-card-header>
            <h2>{{item.titulo}}</h2>
          </ion-card-header>
        </div>

        <!-- Descripción -->
        <div class="col-12 mt-1 mt-md-2  contenedor-txt">
          <p class="cortarTexto">{{item.descripcion}} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam enim sed mollitia molestias, quia repellat optio nemo atque quaerat. Quis accusantium ut consequuntur fugiat perferendis nobis sapiente quod architecto. Adipisci.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Botón Más -->
        <div class="col-12  mt-2 d-flex justify-content-end  contenedor-boton">
          <button [routerLink]="['/home/programa', item.id]" class="">más</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```